# DevOps with Azure PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure-devops, azure-postgresql

I know that this is general question which is not really the normal type of question but I have been looking around and I cannot find and detail on how to set this up.

What I would like to do is figure out have the schema of my Postgres database which is and Azure Postgres SQL database stores in source control and when changes are made it triggers a build and deploys the change into another server using azure DevOps.

Comment: `Azure Postgres SQL database stores in source control`.  What type of file do you use as source control repo?  I am not sure what file you used to save and deploy changes. You can share some of the steps you have done, and then I will try to find the process that suits you situation.

Comment: That is really the problem. Currently the only way I can find to even get anything into source control is to manually creat a script and upload. So I’m looking for guidance even on integrated into source control so it can be a more seamless and less manual effort.

Comment: Since you want to use Sql Script to change the azure database, you could try to use the [Azure SQL Database deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops). It supports to use Dacpac file and Sql script to deploy the database.  This is [a tutorial](https://medium.com/@harioverhere/deploying-azure-sql-database-schema-using-azure-devops-and-azure-resource-manager-tenplates-3aa9d741d267), it might give you some help